# Paperclip gives an error, possibly due to wrong path variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip with Rails 3. Trying to upload an image. I've looked at some other questions but I can't seem to solve it.

I get this error trying to save my model:

```
Photo C:/Users/Benjamin/AppData/Local/Temp/ben_2.png20120408-3864-l1w6rb is not        recognized by the 'identify' command.
Photo C:/Users/Benjamin/AppData/Local/Temp/ben_2.png20120408-3864-l1w6rb is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

in my development.rb I have

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.7.6-Q16/convert"
```

Running which convert gives me:

```
$ which convert
/c/Windows/system32/convert
```

Running which identify gives me :

```
$ which identify
//empty line
```

My path is something like this:

C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.6-Q16;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Smart Projects\IsoBuster;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oh yeah I tried doing which identify and there is a line break and nothing else.

Comment: Do you have the PNG library installed with imagemagick? Check identify syntax help - there is an option in there to display the formats it has knowledge of.

Comment: jpegs don't work either so I'm guessing that's not the error?

Comment: Both JPEG and PNG libraries are not part of standard imagemagick install, at least on *nix. Not sure about the Windows installer. Check.

Comment: Seems to know about 

`C:\Users\Benjamin>identify -list type
Bilevel
ColorSeparation
ColorSeparationMatte
Grayscale
GrayscaleMatte
Optimize
Palette
PaletteBilevelMatte
PaletteMatte
TrueColorMatte
TrueColor`.

Plus I can convert png and jpegs from the command line. So looks like it's set up ok there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a reinstall of imagemagick.